# Search pattern from a file into another file

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I have `file1` with numbers in four columns, each has 16 digits:

```
5150782703810496 7071783126930570 9776701040412294 4414890272061604
6426318539518073 5261792065926013 6303463168130122 8332314317620078
7506133106243886 2242241367012197 8275982207923757 7263931623813806
8882831187329643 3184441663826305 1416431572523093 0697142167966828
```

In `file2` I have 16 search patterns (sorted here by chance), one for each number in `file1`:

```
0412294
062438
118732964
157252
17831269305
23813806
24224136701
3323143
381049
441489027206160
441663826305
5926013
66828
68130
82207923
8539518073
```

Now I'm searching for a solution to find `row` and `column` for each pattern from `file2` in `file1`. Desired result in `file3`:

```
1,1=381049
1,2=17831269305
1,3=0412294
1,4=441489027206160
2,1=8539518073
2,2=5926013
2,3=68130
2,4=3323143
3,1=062438
3,2=24224136701
3,3=82207923
3,4=23813806
4,1=118732964
4,2=441663826305
4,3=157252
4,4=66828
```

I tried it with `grep -f file2 file1` and found the `row` but no `column`. I'm on Windows and would prefer `awk`, `grep` or `sed` and can not use `Perl` and `Bash` unfortunately. How to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution.

Content of `script.awk`:

```
FNR == NR {
    patterns[ $1 ] = 1 
    next
}

{
    for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { 
        for ( p in patterns ) { 
            if ( index( $i, p ) > 0 ) { 
                printf "%d,%d=%s\n", FNR, i, p
                delete patterns[ p ] 
                break
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk file2 file1
```

That yields:

```
1,1=381049
1,2=17831269305
1,3=0412294
1,4=441489027206160
2,1=8539518073
2,2=5926013
2,3=68130
2,4=3323143
3,1=062438
3,2=24224136701
3,3=82207923
3,4=23813806
4,1=118732964
4,2=441663826305
4,3=157252
4,4=66828
```

Answer (score 4):

Output is not sorted. [Birei's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17013956/970195) solution does exactly what you need.

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[$i]=NR","i 
    }
    next
} 
{ 
    b[$1] 
} 
END {
    for (x in a) { 
        for (y in b) {
            if (index(x,y)>0) {
                print a[x]"="y
            }
        }
    }
}' file1 file2
```

#### Output:

```
4,4=66828
4,1=118732964
3,3=82207923
4,3=157252
4,2=441663826305
2,4=3323143
1,1=381049
2,1=8539518073
3,2=24224136701
1,3=0412294
2,3=68130
1,2=17831269305
2,2=5926013
1,4=441489027206160
3,1=062438
3,4=23813806
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|s/(.*=).*(&).*/\\1\\2/p|' file2 |
sed -nrf - <(sed = file1 | sed -r 'N;s/^(.*)\n(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)/\1,1=\2\n\1,2=\3\n\1,3=\4\n\1,4=\5/') >file3
```

Transform `file1` into a file with one set of numbers per line and add the line number and row.
From `file2` create a sed script and run it against the above file ouput. 
However since you are on windows I guess you will need to break each step into a separate file and run it in three steps.

Comment: Works great, I love it!! In Windows the second step is `sed = file1 | sed -r "N;s/^(.*)\n(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)/\1,1=\2\n\1,2=\3\n\1,3=\4\n\1,4=\5/"|sed -nrf file3.sed>file3` where file3.sed is the script from step #1. Thank you so much!

Comment: WTF!! +1 just coz it's `sed` solution posted by the master himself.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bash script (you did not rule bash out) like:

```
IFS=$'\n'
lnum=0
for line in $(cat file1); do
    lnum=$(( lnum + 1 ))
    cnum=0
    IFS=' '
    for entry in $line; do
        cnum=$(( cnum + 1 ))
        IFS=$'\n'
        for pattern in $(cat file2); do
            if [[ $entry =~ ^.*${pattern}.*$ ]]; then
                echo "${lnum},${cnum}=${pattern}"
                break
            fi
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm on Windows and would not install `Cygwin`. Updated my question.

Comment: @captcha How do you plan on running awk and grep and such on Windows?

Comment: @squiguy I can use all Unix tools from [GNU win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)